# StackOverflowError occurred when loading data from database

Tags: java, json, entity-framework, spring-data-jpa

i have java application with connetion to database with jpa framework.
Object `UserInformation` contains `AdditionData` object, when I do `userInformationRepository.findByUserId(id)` receive error.
In response I see json with many inner objects

```
userInformation->additionData->userInformation->userInformation->additionData->userInformation->....
```

Exception:

```
>java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.entity.UserInformation.toString()


java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.checkContentLength(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:232) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.access$200(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:33) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:637) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2033) ~[jackson-core-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeRaw(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:632) ~[jackson-core-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeRaw(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:555) ~[jackson-core-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeNumber(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:931) ~[jackson-core-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializers$FloatSerializer.serialize(NumberSerializers.java:194) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
```

**UserInformation** entity

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "user_information")
public class UserInformation {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "title", length = 64)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "message", length = 128)
    private String message;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userInformation")
    private AdditionData additionData;
}
```

**AdditionData** entity

```
@Setter @Getter
@Entity(name = "addition_data")
public class AdditionData {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private UserInformation userInformation;
}
```

Repository for `UserInformation` entity

```
@Repository
public interface UserInformationRepository extends CrudRepository<UserInformation, Long> {
    List<UserInformation> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
    UserInformation findByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

Why error occurred? Do I have error in configuration for relations in entity?

Comment: Did you override `toString()` method on those entities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally jackson JSON serialization into problems with cyclical links. Like the one between your two entities (`UserInformation` has an `AdditionData` which has the same `UserInformation` etc).

Add `@JsonIgnore` one of the members to stop the cycle. For good measure I would add an exclude to your lombok `@Data` annotation to prevent the issue when `toString()` is called.

Using `@JsonIgnore` will prevent spring's Jackson JSON serializer from running through the references when output is generated as JSON. Since that process is recursive (members are serialized to json as well), preventing diving into those references will also prevent the `StackOverflowException` from being thrown.

Comment: thanks for answer, i remove `@Data` and added `@Getter` `@Setter` annotation but it not solve problem, but why?
With `@JsonIgnore` it work perfectly.

Comment: Added some details that I hope will clarify my answer somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me!